# Purpose of joining multiple words in tags with hyphens

Tags: discussion, tags

I see here on Stack sites that tag names join multiple words with a hyphen. What, exactly, is the purpose of that? As long as my syntax is right, what does it matter if I'm searching for "multiple word" or "multiple-word"?

Answer (score 5):

A question about `egg-cups` is not the same as a question about `egg`s or one about `cups`. An egg-cup expert might want to see questions about egg-cups without being swamped with stupid questions about other kinds of cup; an expert on paper cups might want to ignore questions about egg-cups.

Comment: Replace eggs with waffles and cups with iron and you have a winner.

Comment: +1 for getting right to the point and, well, being *correct*.

Comment: Curses, you're right: this answer contains insufficient meme. Excuse: I was still in SO mode instead of Meta. Many apologies; I'll be certain to include twice the normal quota of pony-waffles in the next one. Mmm, delicious pony-waffles.